# Rails / Devise / Mailer: Throwing 'config.action_mailer.default_url_options' error on attempted registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sendmail, mailer

It's just been one problem after another today. I just deployed to my production server and testing it out, with issues whenever anything involves email. Particularly with Devise's confirmable registration email, whenever I sign up for an account, the following error is thrown up in the log...

```
ActionView::Template::Error (You can no longer call ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options directly. You need to set config.action_mailer.default_url_options. If you are using ActionMailer standalone, you need to include the routing url_helpers directly.):
```

Looking at my config/environments/production.rb, I have the following set...

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }
```

So config.action_mailer.default_url_options **IS** being used, but is being completely ignored. I tried changing the host to '127.0.0.1' and my server's IP addy, but it wouldn't have it. Threw it in config/application.rb, but no go. I hunted in my project for any other lines declaring default_url_options, but it's only set in the production.rb file. I Googled and found a post suggesting to set config.cache_classes to false, but negative there as well.

Now here is what's crazy...I got the same error whenever I tried to submit a brand new comment in my project (set up to send an email to confirm the email address if you are a first time commentor). I took OUT config.action_mailer...etc from the production.rb file, and viola - my comment mailer worked and sent the email just fine!

Still, Devise is being absolutely stubborn and keeps throwing the above error at me. Any ideas on why? BTW, all my gems are up to date. Below is my production.rb file.

--- **UPDATE** ---------------

Have made a little progress, but this is just weird. When I start the server and attempt to do something that will send mail (user registration, comment), I get the ActionMailer::Base error message above. When I try the action AGAIN...it works and the mail gets sent. From that point on (until Passenger and/or the server is rebooted), all mailer actions work fine.

But not without yet another issue (it never ends)...for some reason the email body is completely blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up hitting this problem once again when I attempted to test in the test database, and I was determined once and for all to figure out why I was getting this error, and why no one else seemed to have come across it (very little results from Google).

After completely tearing down my project and reconstructing it, I finally pinpointed the issues to the Sitemap-generator plugin I had installed. Once I removed all traces of that, the above error finally ceased.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on this issue for Fat Free CRM, and I realized that this error happens because Rails 3 lazy-loads classes. All you need to do is 'touch' the ActionMailer::Base class in your environments/**.rb files, and it will load the class. Then you can call ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options from a controller, etc. (We do this so that we can automatically set the mailer host from request.host_with_port)

So my environment files now look like this:

```
FatFreeCRM::Application.configure do

  ...

  ActionMailer::Base
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved this issue...though I'm not "exactly" sure what did it. It very well may have been config.cache_classes = true which I commented out, and although I was concerned this would effect my site caching or something else, it doesn't seem to have broke it.

In addition, the empty email body I solved by switching from :sendmail to :smtp.

Here is my final production.rb file, hopefully this might be of use to someone with a similar issue in the future.

```
MyProject::Application.configure do

  # Commented out, causes 'ActionView::Template' error
  #config.cache_classes = true

  config.whiny_nils = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  config.action_view.debug_rjs = true

  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  Sunspot.config.solr.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr'

  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => "user@domain.com",
    :password => 'password'
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'dev.mydomain.com' }

  config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"

end
```